# react-beautiful-dnd How to styling for dragging item when outside the Droppable

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I want to customize the style of dragging item when I drag it outside of the Dragale component.
Currently: I want to change cursor CSS to "all-scroll" but it just affects inside the Dragale component. It doesn't affect when outside the Dragale component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vertical-list-forked-ifl58?file=/index.js

Please help me and thank you so much.

Current observe snap screen:

[image: current observe snap screen]

Answer (score 4):

```
const getItemStyle = (isDragging, draggableStyle) => ({
  ...draggableStyle
  cursor: isDragging ? "all-scroll" : "pointer",
});
```

Comment: Thank you baymax, but it still doesn't show "all-scroll" cursor when I drag item outside the Dragale component.

Comment: Probably because you have to do the spreading before assigning cursor value? Else the value is just overwritten. e.g:
```
{
  ...draggableStyle,
  cursor: isDragging ? "all-scroll" : "pointer"
}
```